# Use each node of Hazelcast to have a backup of every map and force read from backup

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I have a use case where I have to make every machine of my Hazelcast cluster to act as a backup of every map. Also, I want to ensure that data is always read from backup. 
I cannot hard code the number of back-ups something like this 
"1" as I keep adding/removing machines. So this has to be dynamic. 
Can someone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ain't that already the default behaviour when you have backups enabled? Since data (primary + backup) in Hazelcast is partitioned, each of the node in the cluster will be primary to some of the total cluster data and will also store portion of data from other nodes as backup. So, if you have 3000 entries to store in a 3 nodes cluster with 1 backup, each of the nodes will have 1000 entries as primary and 2000 (1000 each from other 2 nodes) as backup of data stored on other 2 nodes. You can read from backup by setting   to true.